# Get Http error from Ajax triggered by async click event with ZombieJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, zombie.js

So I have a webpage which uses knockout and I have a click handler. Once clicked it fires off an ajax request to an API server which returns a contextual HttpStatus result.

So for example if I was unauthorised I would get a 401 response, if it was ok I would get 200. So the question is based around how can I capture the error in Zombie as the `.click("#some-button", function(error) { /* No Error */ })` is returning no error from the callback, so is there some other way to try and catch the http status codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [zombieJS API](http://zombie.labnotes.org/API), you can get the status codes by this method : `browser.statusCode`.